# phpQuery проверка на существование div

Tags: php

Есть страницы на которых находятся div'ы с views-row-1 от 1 до 11.
Пример:

```
<div class="views-row views-row-1 quotes-row">
```

Но есть страницы на которых div'ы не до 11 а до другого числа <11
При парсинге этих страниц надо сделать проверку на существование div'а с последующим номером(если существует то парсить содержимое, а если нет то соответственно не парсить)
Как я могу это реализовать (На php 7)

Comment: Можно парсить все возможные, а потом посчитать их количество.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

```
preg_match_all("/(\s)(views-row-)[1-9]*(\s)/", $pageStr, $out);
$res = count($out[0]);
```

Где `$pageStr` - текст вашей страницы.

В `$res` у вас будет количество совпадений. Если у вас нумируются ваши блоки по-порядку, то `$res` - это ваш последний элемент.

К примеру, если он равен `5`, это значит, что у вас есть элементы:

```
<div class="views-row views-row-1 quotes-row">
<div class="views-row views-row-2 quotes-row">
<div class="views-row views-row-3 quotes-row">
<div class="views-row views-row-4 quotes-row">
<div class="views-row views-row-5 quotes-row">
```

Значит нет элементов, начиная с `views-row-6` и заканчивая `views-row-11`.